# Move UIView per UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, animation, uibezierpath

I've a **UIBezierPath** drawing this

[image]

And I want the red point to move on the blue path infinitely (from right to left, from left to right)

How can I do that?

Comment: pls show the code how u have drawn the blue path and red path.

Comment: As a screenshot in comments to first answer (below)

Comment: I have a solution, but it is  worth to give it a try. Once you have the bezier path(blue), create a clone of blue bezier path and put it on top of the blue bezier curve. GIve the clone a red color.Now change the red bezier path to dashes a, modify the dashes so that there will be only one dash in the path. Now you can animate the phase of the bezier path, and this red dash will move along the its path.This will give the impression that red is following the blue path.

Comment: Learn to create a [mcve]. We don't have your code or any proof that you've performed any research. We can't answer your question in this format. Please [edit]  your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAKeyFrameAnimation`. Assign your path to the `path` property of the animation object, then run the animation on the view's layer.

**Edit**:

A little snippet as a hint:

```
let path = ... // the UIBezierPath
let animation = CAKeyFrameAnimation()
animation.path = path.CGPath
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced // This give the animation an even pace
animation.repeatCount = HUGE // This makes the animation repeat forever

viewToAnimation.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: May I ask for a little code example? I'm now in custom UIView, drawing path in drawRect function

Comment: @SwiftStudier see my edited answer.

Comment: Nothing happens. What is my mistake? (code: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimokekrana2016-08-04v11.1470298823.png)

Comment: Don't add subviews and run animations inside 'drawRect'. This method is called every frame.

Comment: if some desperate soul still looking for the CORRECT answer, here's the code:
let animationSpark = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animationSpark.path = path.cgPath
        animationSpark.calculationMode = .paced
        animationSpark.duration = 1.75
spark.layer.add(animationSpark, forKey: "SparkAnimation")