# Moving UILabel along a BezierPath For some duration

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, caanimation

I have a situation where I wanted to move one Label along a Bezier Path which is working fine. However, when I switch app from foreground to background and again to foreground, the moving is not proper. I have used CAAnimation for positioning.

```
    let path = circularBezierPathForLabel().cgPath
    bubbleLabel.center = path.currentPoint
    bubbleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = bubbleLabel.bounds.size.width / 2.0
    bubbleLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    bubbleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.addSublayer(bubbleLabel.layer)

    let textAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    textAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(duration)
    let pathValues = self.pathValuesWithVariance(amountOfDegrees: 1)

    var pathPoints = [CGPoint]()
    for path in pathValues {
        let currentPoint = path.currentPoint
        pathPoints.append(currentPoint)
    }
    textAnimation.values = pathPoints
    textAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear
    bubbleLabel.layer.add(textAnimation, forKey: "position")
```

Is there any other way to solve this foreground and background thing in CAAnimation? Any help would be great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761706/2526932
Take a look at this

Comment: @rv7284, your link doesn't work for background to foreground.